# Parsing two (or more) JSON requests to a single ListView [Android]

Tags: android, json, listview

I am trying to parse two (or more) JSON requests to a single ListView. Is that even possible?

Now, im using `JsonArrayRequest` along with the `RequestQueue.add()`. 
And it works perfectly, the only issue is - when I try to add another JSON request to the request queue it mixes them up in the `ListView` - sometimes the second request is above the first one and vice versa.   It should be a *Section Header*, followed by the *First Request*, then another *Section Header*, and then the *Second Request*. Both the requests are from the same table just different `WHERE` parameters.
I really could not identify any logical pattern so I'm assuming it is done randomly. How or why is that happening?

Comment: Are you adding to the `ListView` from two different Threads?

Comment: Same Thread, one is ran after another. Same function even.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably adding to the `ListView` from two separate Threads.

You have two options, Either wait for the first Thread to finish then run the second one. (in `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`).
OR
you can run both Threads but only call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after the execution of whichever runs **last** thread. you can use a boolean to indicate which thread runs last.

Comment: Same Thread, same function. I tried the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` method before but that did not work.